# Vue Bootstrap Array of strings comma seperated from text area?

Tags: vue.js, textarea, bootstrap-vue

I need to extract strings from a text area in vue bootstrap and save them into an array. These are number and alpha strings, and when someone puts a coma they separate. Bonus if we could do it so they appear are 'pills' or tags in a tag add input field. Read the documentation could not find anything specifically for this, thanks so much for any help.

Comment: [JavaScript String split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Comment: do i use a v-model to save them into an array? im just really confused i know i have to use the split somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The splitting shouldn't be too difficult, just manually bind the input and parse the output from the textarea, converting to and from the data array appropriately for each.

For the textarea's *input* value:

- Concat the array elements together, with `,`  separating each element
- We can use `list.join(', ')` to accomplish this

For the textarea's *output* value:

- We can bind a handler to one of the events that [Bootstrap-Vue's textarea](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-textarea) emits, in this case I used `update` since that's what [BV uses for `v-model`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-textarea#comp-ref-b-form-textarea-v-model)
- That handler will translate the text into our array:

  - Split the sting into an array on commas: `value.split(",")`
  - Trim each element to remove preceding/ trailing whitespace: `.map(item => item.trim())`
  - Then filter out any empty elements: `.filter(item => item.length > 0)`

This input/ output logic will appropriately translate the textarea's contents into an array and vice-versa.

As for the pills, I'm not sure if what I've done below is exactly what you're looking for, but I thought I'd give it a shot.

---

#### Functioning Example

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      listArr: ["test", "1", "2"],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    arrToText() {
      return this.listArr.join(', ');
    },
  },
  methods: {
    textToArr(value) {
      this.listArr = value.split(",")
        .map(item => item.trim())
        .filter(item => item.length > 0);
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<!-- Set up Vue and Bootstrap-Vue for snippet -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@4/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" /><script src="//unpkg.com/vue@2/dist/vue.min.js"></script><script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-form-textarea :value="arrToText" class="mb-2" @update="textToArr"></b-form-textarea>
  <h3>
    <b-badge v-for="(item, index) in listArr" :key="index" pill variant="primary" class="mr-2">{{ item }}</b-badge>
  </h3>
</div>
```